# How convert a non-generic List to a List<String>?

Tags: java, java-stream

When I try to convert using Java 8 streams, I get a compile error:

> Incompatible types
>   Required: List
>   Found: java.lang.Object

```
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("Test");
    list.add("Java");
    list.add("Other");

    //This won't compile
    List<String> strings = list.stream()
        .map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Don't use *raw* generic types, aka non-generic list. Just change code to `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @Andreas I'd guess from the title that he can't change that for some reason

Comment: If you know it's a `List<String>` can't you just cast it? `((List<String>)list).stream()`

Comment: @eis Correct. I'm actually calling a 3rd party method that returns `List`

Comment: You can cast it to `List<String>` without a problem

Comment: even `map(String::valueOf)` can do the trick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026436/how-convert-a-non-generic-list-to-a-liststring/50026565#comment87069267_50026436):

> I'm actually calling a 3rd party method that returns `List`

Then cast the value to a `List<Object>` or `List<?>` *([thanks, Sean Van Gorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026436/how-convert-a-non-generic-list-to-a-liststring/50026565#comment87078353_50026565))* so it is not a *raw* generic anymore, and the stream code will work:

```
List<?> list = thirdPartyMethod();

List<String> strings = list.stream()
        .map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Logically, there is no difference between a `List` and a `List<Object>`, but there is a big difference to the compiler, because a *raw* generic forces backwards-compatibility mode in the compiler, where *all* generics are ignored, causing the entire stream-chain to behave badly.

Comment: Or cast it directly: `(List<String>) thirdPartyMethod()`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman The returned list is likely not a list of strings, otherwise the `Objects.toString` wouldn't be needed. For that stream-chain, the starting point would be a list of some kind of object, but probably not a list of strings.

Comment: `List<?> list` should fix the unchecked warning.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code

**Edited  Complete Code**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

    public class MyFunction {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
            list.add("Test");
            list.add("Java");
            list.add("Other");
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<String> strings = (List<String>) list.stream().map(object -> Objects.toString(object, null))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            System.out.println(strings.get(0));
        }
    }
```

This code  will compile successfully and will run as well.

Comment: Since OP is using `Objects.toString` to convert an `Object` to a `String`, you should cast to `List<Object>`.

Comment: Better to cast to a `List<Object>` immediately before calling `stream()` so all the stream operations can be done with checked generics.